# How to merge multiple tables in mysql

Tags: mysql

How to merge multiple tables with difference column name in one table?

I have table 1 and table 2, so i want to merge fields of table2 into table1.

For example:

**Table 1**

```
ID NAME
1  A
2  B
3  C
```

**Table 2**

```
SEX Address
M   A
F   B
M   C
```

Result that I need as the following:

**Result**

```
ID NAME SEX  ADDRESS
1  A    M    A
2  B    F    B
3  C    M    C
```

How to do that in mysql ?

Comment: You should read about `JOINS` in relational databases. Actually you should have read some manual _before_ asking here. Your question is answered in any introduction out there.

Comment: Your `Table 2` does not have ID ? if so, I think that is impossible to have a correct result, otherwise, use `JOIN` like the answer

Comment: bad shema structure. you should use relation id between tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**[Here is the SQLFiddel working Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/dfe1b/13)**

**Below is the Query which You can try**

```
select T1.ID,T1.Name,T2.Sex,T2.Address
  from 
(select *,@Row1 := @Row1 + 1 as rownum
  from Table1
  join (select @Row1 := 0) r) as T1
join
(select *,@Row2 := @Row2 + 1 as rownum
  from Table2
  join (select @Row2 := 0) r) as T2
Where T1.rownum = T2.rownum
```

Answer (score 0):

Do something like this:

```
SELECT t1.ID, t1.NAME, t2.SEX, t2.ADDRESS from table1 t1 cross join table2 t2;
```

**OR**

```
SELECT t1.ID, t1.NAME, t2.SEX, t2.ADDRESS from table1 t1, table2 t2;
```